# How to perform a partial F test in a python on only some of the model variables

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statistical-test

I want to build a regression model with 65 variables in python.
Then, I want to perform a partial F test only on 2 selected variables in python.

In the partial F test, H0 will be the hypothesis that the two Beta (coefficient of the selected variable in the model) of the two variables are equal to 0.
H1 will be the hypothesis that at least one of the Beta is not equal to 0.

I searched everywhere and found no answer to my question.
I would be happy for your help.

Answer (score 3):

For more details, you can check the [help page for f test on statsmodels results](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.f_test.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.f_test).

For example your data is like this (i use only 5 variables):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

np.random.seed(999)

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(50,6)),
                   columns=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','y'])
```

We can fit the regression and results look like:

```
results = sm.OLS(endog= data['y'],exog=sm.add_constant(data.iloc[:,:5])).fit()
results.summary()

    coef    std err t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
const   0.7432  0.201   3.700   0.001   0.338   1.148
x1  -0.0345 0.147   -0.235  0.816   -0.331  0.262
x2  -0.1758 0.151   -1.165  0.250   -0.480  0.128
x3  -0.1472 0.150   -0.982  0.331   -0.449  0.155
x4  -0.2735 0.144   -1.905  0.063   -0.563  0.016
x5  0.1143  0.135   0.845   0.403   -0.158  0.387
```

Set up the hypothesis, in this case x3 and x4 are zero, then perform the test:

```
hypotheses = '(x3 = 0), (x4 = 0)'
f_test = results.f_test(hypotheses)
print(f_test)

<F test: F=array([[2.64119819]]), p=0.08255414803527926, df_denom=44, df_num=2>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do that with sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression?